# Symfony batch requests kernel execution time

Tags: php, symfony, batch-processing

I am trying to perform bulk operations using a command line tool and the `http_kernel` component.

I have stored the requests in a database and, using a command, i'm trying to use my controllers internally by calling `$kernel->handle($request);` for every request.

The problem is that the execution time of each request is growing up over time.

This command has been run in a test environment and I am sure the execution will be much more faster on the production server.

**Edit: I have about 10.000 requests to be executed, and all those requests are very similar**

However, I would like to know if there is an optimisation that could be done to ensure **a stable execution time** for the whole batch.

Here is my code:

```
$kernel = $this->getContainer()->get('http_kernel');

foreach ($requests as $request) {

        $start = round(microtime(true) * 1000);

        $response = $kernel->handle($request);
        $kernel->terminate($request, $response);

        $requestDuration = (round(microtime(true) * 1000) - $start);

        $output->writeln(($response->isSuccessful() ? ' . ' : ' X ') . '(' . $handleDuration . ')');
}
```

Here is an example output : (`.` stands for a successfull request; the time (ms) is in parentheses)

```
. (246 ms)
. (275 ms)
. (271 ms)
. (268 ms)
. (564 ms)
. (379 ms)
. (353 ms)
. (321 ms)
[...]
. (416 ms)
. (425 ms)
. (409 ms)
. (448 ms)
. (402 ms)
. (405 ms)
. (410 ms)
. (453 ms)
. (476 ms)
. (462 ms)
. (488 ms)
[...]
. (564 ms)
. (537 ms)
. (553 ms)
. (564 ms)
. (510 ms)
. (564 ms)
. (531 ms)
. (569 ms)
. (655 ms)
[...]
. (1155 ms)
. (1179 ms)
. (1142 ms)
. (1126 ms)
```

Thank you for your help !

**(Edit)**

Here are some details about the actions performed by the controller :

```
public function postEntityAction(Request $request) {
    // get the authenticated user
    $authUser = $this->getUser();
    // fetch some data from the database (there is about 6 calls like this one that could be done during the process)
    // note: the hydrator used by all my repository methods is SIMPLEOBJECT
    $item = $itemRepository->getItemById($request->request->get('itemId'));
    // create an entity and set its fields
    $entity = new Entity();
    $entity->setItem($item);
    // I also do some validations using the validator service
    $validator = $this->get('validator');
    $validator->validate($entity);
    // I persist the new entity
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($entity);
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
    // and finally I return the serialized object (using JMS serializer)
    return $this->serialize($entity);
}
```

Comment: It really depends on the operations triggered by the request. I would guess that there is some data processing, and the amount of data to be processed grows with each request (or: over time). It would be interesting to learn more about the actual operations being performed in the controllers/services involved. Can you please add those (in an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) style) to your post?

Comment: I should have precised that all those requests are very similar, it consists of the following steps:
1) verifies some values in the request.
2) inserts the new Entity in the database.
I will update my post with more details about it

Comment: you should definetly check if execution time also grows up on production environment. My guess is that entityManager fills up some kind of object-cache maybe try `$em->clear();` . In terms of optimisation i would generaly flush on every batch not every request.

Comment: @alchm: Can you determine the `microtime` timings for the steps in your `postEntityAction`, i.e. how long every step takes? Do they all increase? Also, what happens if you clear the database, do the running times decrease?

Comment: For now, I've tried the following things, with no real success . 
**1)** Tried to call `$em->clear();` but with no visible effect . 
**2)** I cleared my controller with the minimum amount of code (`get the values` from the Request object, `create` the new Entity and `persist` it) the result is a faster execution time, but still growing . 
**3)** Worst case: I removed the `persist` step... and it is still growing.

Comment: @johnSmith I totally agree with you, using a batch would be better, but my purpose here is to perform some requests that were stored in the first time (business related feature) so It doesn't really matter if each request takes 200 or 700 ms, the problem is this growing execution time :)
Is there any know memory or cache issue within the Symfony HTTP kernel that would lead to this ?

Comment: @alchm as far as i can see it is not necessery to handle those saved "requests" as actual kernel requests/controller/response scenario. You should seperate the processing of these into a service and use actual batching then, controller and command could share the service->method then

Comment: Yes, you are totally right, my controller lacks a bit of separation, and using internal requests was an easy way to solve this problem.
But I still don't understand why doing 100+ requests inside the same http kernel would lead to this kind of problem.
Thanks for your help